# How to make links in a hidden list items clickable

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm creating a Menu for a responsive page with only Html and CSS. When the page is less than 850px(for tablets and mobiles) the horizontal menu is hidden and users have to click a button to access the menu. Its a single page with smooth-scrolling.

However when you open the menu, the links don't click. I've noticed that when the I unhide the menu the links work fine. How do I make the links clickable? I thought it might have something to do with the links being "overlayed" by another item.

Any help would appreciated

```css
/*********** HIDDEN MENU section  *************/



#hidden-menu-items {
 display: none;
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 2;
}

/******* This displays the menu on click *******/

input[type=image]{
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=image]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=image]:focus + ul#hidden-menu-items {
 display: block;
}
```

````html
Here's the HTML
```
<!-- Hidden Mobile Menu-->

      <div id="hidden-menu">
          <input type="image" src="images/menu-button-red-png.png" alt="menu-button" class="menu-button">

        <!-- Hidden Menu Items-->

          <ul id="hidden-menu-items">
            <li><a href="#title">About the avengers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#avengers">Meet our heros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#movies-list">Movie Timeline</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Upcoming Movies</a></li>
          </ul> 
      </div>
````

Comment: _“I thought it might have something to do with the links being "overlayed" by another item.”_ - that’s usually easy enough to verify, if you move the cursor over the element, and then right click and inspect … if there is other stuff on top of the link, then you land there in the elements panel, and not on your link.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle with your problem?

Comment: I see, thanks 04FS, it seems that the links are on right on top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click the link, the image input will loose focus (blur) and the links disappear
The blur event takes place before the click event, and so you cannot use the click on something that is not there.

Use `:focus-within` on the parent

```css
/*********** HIDDEN MENU section  *************/

#hidden-menu-items {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}


/******* This displays the menu on click *******/

input[type=image] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hidden-menu:focus-within {
  outline: none;
}

#hidden-menu:focus-within #hidden-menu-items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Hidden Mobile Menu-->

<div id="hidden-menu">
  <input type="image" src="images/menu-button-red-png.png" alt="menu-button" class="menu-button">

  <!-- Hidden Menu Items-->

  <ul id="hidden-menu-items">
    <li><a href="#title">About the avengers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#avengers">Meet our heros</a></li>
    <li><a href="#movies-list">Movie Timeline</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Upcoming Movies</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But: you can't use focus-within, because you ! [caniuse: CSS focus-within](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within)

For a solution without JS and `focus-within` use hidden radio buttons and the CSS sibling combinator `~` along with the `:checked` pseudo-class.

```css
/*********** HIDDEN MENU section  *************/

.hidden-menu-items {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}


/******* This displays the menu on click *******/

.menu-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-open-indicator,
.menu-close-indicator {
  display: none;
}
.menu-open-indicator:checked ~ .menu-open,
.menu-close {
  display: none;
}
.menu-open-indicator:checked ~ .menu-close,
.menu-open-indicator:checked ~ .hidden-menu-items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Hidden Mobile Menu-->

<div class="hidden-menu">
  <input type="radio" name="menu-toggle" id="my-menu-open" class="menu-open-indicator">
  <input type="radio" name="menu-toggle" id="my-menu-close" class="menu-close-indicator">
  <label class="menu-open" for="my-menu-open">
    <img src="images/menu-button-red-png.png" alt="menu-button" class="menu-button">
  </label>
  <label class="menu-close" for="my-menu-close">
    <img src="images/menu-button-red-png.png" alt="menu-button" class="menu-button">
  </label>

  <!-- Hidden Menu Items-->

  <ul class="hidden-menu-items">
    <li><a href="#title">About the avengers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#avengers">Meet our heros</a></li>
    <li><a href="#movies-list">Movie Timeline</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Upcoming Movies</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @yunzen, this is exactly what I was looking for. It worked perfectly. I see that about 80% of browsers support this feature. Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari and IOS. [link](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within)

Comment: Oops! you're right. How important is it though to target every browser? I mean, from the numbers it seems the world has already decided against MS Browsers. And a browser like UC has 3% marketshare but is filled with malware.

Answer (score 3):

I think the input loses focus once you click the links, so they become hidden again.

I would suggest using jQuery to add/remove a class on click and adjusting the CSS according to this (or just changing the CSS with jQuery).

Here's the example:

```js
$('#hidden-menu input').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#hidden-menu-items').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
#hidden-menu-items {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

#hidden-menu-items.visible {
  display: block;
}

#hidden-menu {
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hidden-menu">
  <input type="image" src="images/menu-button-red-png.png" alt="menu-button" class="menu-button">

  <!-- Hidden Menu Items-->
  <ul id="hidden-menu-items">
    <li><a href="#title">About the avengers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#avengers">Meet our heros</a></li>
    <li><a href="#movies-list">Movie Timeline</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Upcoming Movies</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

And a link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mzLwg0xb/.

Comment: A VanillaJS solution would be: `document.getElementById('hidden-menu').querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('hidden-menu-items').classList.toggle('visible')
})
`

Comment: Thanks @kristinadavidovic, this works perfectly too. I haven't learned any jQuery yet but so I prefer the CSS solution.

Comment: @WayneRichardhendricks no problem. You have the jQuery solution here as well so if you need it in the future you know where to look. :) I'm glad you got the answer.